# How to generate a test directory using Rails 4 for minitest procedures?

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, tdd, minitest

I have a question in regards to generating a test directory in my Rails App, I intend on doing unit tests and functional tests all relying on minitest, but I have noticed that rails did not automatically generate a test directory in my app. How do I go about configuring the test environment, so I can properly add a test directory to my app for minitest procedures?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the command

```
rails new some-app-name
```

you should see in the output in the terminal/shell the information that the test directory was created.

```
      .....
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      .....
```

Can you post the command you ran at the shell to create the app ?

Some good background (and current) information on setting up minitest with rails is in [Matt Brictson's Blog](https://mattbrictson.com/minitest-and-rails) .  In this blog post there are some other suggestions about setting up the enhanced display from minitest runs and also recommendations on other gems to use in your rails Gemfile.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I created my Rails app, I did it with using Postgres. I noticed that the app was created without a test directory; I manually inputted one, so now I can conduct the minitests on my code. Does Postgres not include a test directory when generating rails applications?

Comment: The default rails new command should create the directories.  The database type is independent on only influences your config/database.yml.  A simple test is to start with a clean directory and run 'rails new .' (dot for current directory)